# Python: How to query a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have this list of objects:

```
listt = [{
      "CustomerId": "1",
      "Date": "2017-02-02",
      "Content": "AAAAAAAA",
      "Type": 2
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": "2",
      "Date": "2017-02-03",
      "Content": "BBBBBBBB",
      "Type": 1
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": "3",
      "Date": "2017-02-01",
      "Content": "CCCCCCCCC",
      "Type": 1
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": "4",
      "Date": "2017-02-12",
      "Content": "DDDDDDDDDD",
      "Type": 2
    }, ]
```

What's the cleanest way of finding answers to these?

> 1. Minimum Date where Type = 1.

> => 2017-02-1

> 2. Select Content where Type = 2 and Date = (Minimum Date among all objects with Type = 2)

> => AAAAAAAA

I'm reading about leveraging lambda and filters but I haven't been able to make any progress. What can I try next?

Comment: Do you have those objects on your db or just in a list? If they're in db, you can use ORM for query which would be easier and more efficient to retrieve.

Comment: Don't have them in database. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are basic Python data structures. Rather than `map` and `filter` I would suggest using *comprehensions*. E.g.:

```
>>> listt = [{
...       "CustomerId": "1",
...       "Date": "2017-02-02",
...       "Content": "AAAAAAAA",
...       "Type": 2
...     },
...     {
...       "CustomerId": "2",
...       "Date": "2017-02-03",
...       "Content": "BBBBBBBB",
...       "Type": 1
...     },
...     {
...       "CustomerId": "3",
...       "Date": "2017-02-01",
...       "Content": "CCCCCCCCC",
...       "Type": 1
...     },
...     {
...       "CustomerId": "4",
...       "Date": "2017-02-12",
...       "Content": "DDDDDDDDDD",
...       "Type": 2
...     }, ]
>>> min(d['Date'] for d in listt if d['Type'] == 1)
'2017-02-01'
>>>
```

Or, for you second query:

```
>>> min_date = min(d['Date'] for d in listt if d['Type'] == 2)
>>> [d['Content'] for d in listt if d['Date'] == min_date]
['AAAAAAAA']
>>>
```

Trying to stick to comprehension constructs keeps things more readable, IMO, rather than using `lambda`, although, that also has its place and is rather a matter of style. However, list-comprehensions *are faster in general* than equivalent `map` with `lambda`. However, `map` can be faster with built-in functions.

Comment: But it traverses the list twice which I find not to be elegant. It is possible to find both the minimum and the contents with only one list traversal by using the enumerate function - see below.

Comment: @AndiKleve Yes, indeed. It is better to simply return the whole dictionary and query the final key there.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you sir!! I was splitting my hairs understanding filters and lambda. So glad to know there is an easy readable solution to my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

For finding the minimum date with type=1, you may firstly filter the list on type=1 and then pass the filtered list to [**`min`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function *(with key as `lambda x: x['Date']` to find element with minimum 'Date')* as:

```
#                        performs `min` operation on `'Date'` v
>>> min([d for d in listt if d['Type'] ==1], key=lambda x: x['Date'])
{'CustomerId': '3', 'Type': 1, 'Content': 'CCCCCCCCC', 'Date': '2017-02-01'}
```

This is a `dict` object having the minimum `Date` in the list. Let's say it is stored as variable `my_dict`. In order to find the date, do:

```
my_dict['Date']
```

For finding the content associated to it, do:

```
my_dict['Content']
```

*Note:* For finding the content of `Type=2`, replace `d['Type'] ==1` with `d['Type'] ==2` in the `min` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with comprehensions. For the first question:

```
minval = min(elem['CustomerId'] for elem in listt if elem['Type']==1)
print(minval)
```

For the second version, you probably don't want to search for the minimum first and then compare every element to the minimum as this would require to traverse the list twice. Instead, it is better to search for the minimum and keep track of its index. This can be easily done in a comprehension using the `enumerate` function:

```
minval, index = min((elem['CustomerId'], _) 
                    for _, elem in enumerate(listt) if elem['Type']==2)
print(minval, listt[index])
```

Comment: I interpreted the specification to mean "return all contents where" not just the content corresponding to the min value. In which case, two-passes will be needed regardless.

Comment: @juanpa.arivillaga: agree - with this interpretation I also would use two passes.